# Can't import soundfile

Tags: python, conda, librosa

I'm using Anaconda and I'm trying to import soundfile/pysoundfile.

I installed the package by running

```
 conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile
```

and I think it succeeded because when I run

```
 conda list
```

it shows up:

```
pyopenssl                 17.2.0           py36h5d7bf08_0  
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36hb281f35_0  
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36he5c6137_6  
pysocks                   1.6.7            py36hfa33cec_1  
pysoundfile               0.10.1           py_0            conda-forge
pytables                  3.4.2            py36hfbd7ab0_2  
pytest                    3.2.1            py36h9963153_1
```

To make sure I'm running the "right" python, I've tried running

```
which python
```

and I get

```
 /anaconda3/bin/python
```

But when I open python and try running

```
import soundfile
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise OSError('sndfile library not found')
OSError: sndfile library not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 163, in <module>
    _path, '_soundfile_data', _libname))
OSError: cannot load library '/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_soundfile_data/libsndfile.dylib': dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_soundfile_data/libsndfile.dylib, 2): image not found
```

Out of curiosity I opened the soundfile.py file with a text editor to see what line 142 looked like, and it looks like this:

```
try:
    _libname = _find_library('sndfile')
    if _libname is None:
        raise OSError('sndfile library not found')      # <---- line 142
    _snd = _ffi.dlopen(_libname)
except OSError:
    if _sys.platform == 'darwin':
        _libname = 'libsndfile.dylib'
    elif _sys.platform == 'win32':
        from platform import architecture as _architecture
        _libname = 'libsndfile' + _architecture()[0] + '.dll'
    else:
        raise

    # hack for packaging tools like cx_Freeze, which
    # compress all scripts into a zip file
    # which causes __file__ to be inside this zip file

    _path = _os.path.dirname(_os.path.abspath(__file__))

    while not _os.path.isdir(_path):
        _path = _os.path.abspath(_os.path.join(_path, '..'))

    _snd = _ffi.dlopen(_os.path.join(
        _path, '_soundfile_data', _libname))
```

In the docs, it says "import soundfile" is the correct way to import, but I also tried

```
import pysoundfile
```

and only got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysoundfile'
```

Is there anyone who knows why this is happening? I'm running this on MacOS btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the Breaking Changes section [here](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile#breaking-changes)

**we changed the import name from import pysoundfile to import soundfile in 0.7.**

workaround

```
pip install SoundFile
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- I experienced this error as a result of using the `librosa` library, which uses `SoundFile`

  - The `OSError` seems to occur because `SoundFile` is an older version.
  - [GitHub-librosa: Cannot load when importing librosas #1117](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1117)
  - `librosa` seems to install, and should work with `pysoundfile`, but in my experience, it did not.

    - Remove `pysoundfile`: `conda remove pysoundfile --force-remove`
- `SoundFile` is not available for a `conda` install.
- In my case, I had already done `pip uninstall SoundFile`, which then lead to an import error that the package couldn't be found.
- Then I did `pip install SoundFile`, which installed a newer version and resolved the error.
- This worked on Windows 10 with Anaconda, `python 3.8.11`, `SoundFile 0.10.3.post1`, `librosa 0.8.1`

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer. I had the same issue with librosa, now soundfile works fine.