# Can't import soundfile python

Tags: python

while using `import soundfile` on wither python3 or python I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/erezsh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 142, in 
>       raise OSError('sndfile library not found')
>   OSError: sndfile library not found

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916266/cant-import-soundfile) which did not help because I am using `soundfile` and not `pysoundfile` and the link it offers is broken.

Also, [here](https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile/issues/229) I could not find a solution since I have installed using `pip install SoundFile`.

I am using Ubuntu shell on windows. Is this of any importance?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to install the needed library:

> On Linux, you need to install libsndfile using your distribution’s package manager, for example `sudo apt-get install libsndfile1`.

[From PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/)

Comment: This answer helped me run my code in a Linux based docker when my PC is Windows. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

handras answer (from 2019)  is not working now (in 2020) so  install libsndfile1 via ( [as A.B.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680108/package-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path))

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
```

Comment: @havakok Have you noticed "-dev" ? handras answer gives different name of the package.

Comment: No, though I don't see why is it adding on the existing answers?

Comment: @havakok. Because handras answer from 2019 is now working in 2020

Comment: Can you add that to your answer so I can change the vote (locked now)?

Answer (score 8):

Try using the conda installation is you do not have sudo priviliges.

It worked for me, while I continued to face issues via the pip installation.

`conda install -c conda-forge librosa`

The above command installs librosa. You might be able to find a specific one for only soundfile too.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Needed to run `apt update` first, and it worked.

The accepted answer at first did not work for me.

I'm inside a docker image:

```
apt-get install libsndfile1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsndfile1
```

Comment: Running `apt update` was the solution for me in the Deepnote terminal too

Answer (score 3):

in case of yum package manager users first install the dependency

```
 sudo yum -y install libsndfile
```

afterwards run the pip installs

```
pip install SoundFile
pip install librosa
```