# How to use soundfile on heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

I have a python flask app I'm running on Heroku which uses the [`soundfile` library](https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/). After adding `soundfile` to `requirements.txt` Heroku gave me this error:

```
raise OSError('sndfile library not found')
```

I [looked it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086834/cant-import-soundfile-python) and read that I needed the `libsndfile1` library imported. But when I added that to the `requirements.txt` as well, the build failed with the error:

No matching distribution found for libsndfile1

Is there a workaround for importing this package so I can use `soundfile` on Heroku?

Answer (score 13):

`libsndfile1` isn't a Python library, so you can't install it via `requirements.txt`.

One way to get this working is to use the [`apt` buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) alongside the Python buildpack:

1. Remove `libsndfile1` from your `requirements.txt`
2. Configure your application to use two buildpacks:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
   heroku buildpacks
   # Should show apt first, then python
   ```
3. Add an [`Aptfile`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt#aptfile) listing Ubuntu packages to be installed:

   ```
   libsndfile1
   ```

   You may need to include `libsndfile-dev` or `libsndfile1-dev` in this file as well, with each dependency on its own line, depending on the Heroku stack you are using, e.g.

   ```
   libsndfile1
   libsndfile1-dev
   ```
4. Commit your changes and push to deploy. You should see `apt` packages installed first, then your regular Python deployment.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like exactly what I'm looking for! Unfortunately, I tried it and Heroku showed `libsndfile1` as installed in the build but I get the same error when it tries to deploy: `File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 142, in <module> raise OSError('sndfile library not found')`

Comment: @kevinchristianson did you try to add `libsndfile-dev` to `Aptfile` ?

Comment: would you please tell me how to do that on Heroku? Actually, I am a beginner and don't know how to apply these commands and where should it be.

Comment: @codexaxor, this answer already gives step by step instructions. Which part is unclear?

Comment: @Chris first of all thank you. I am on the Heroku dashboard.  I have deployed my git repository. There I got these errors. I couldn't figure out where should I make changes to solve them.

Comment: @codexaxor, steps 1, 3, and 4 are code changes. You'll have to modify your project, commit, and redeploy. Step 2 is how to configure multiple buildpacks on the command line, using the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli). There might be a way to do it via the graphical dashboard, but I've never done that. If you have the CLI installed you should be able to simply run the commands I list in step 2.

Comment: @Chris now it's pretty clear to me. the last query I have no 'Aptfile' file in my project. should I create it? If I have to then where should I locate/keep the file?

Comment: @codexaxor, the `Aptfile` is used by [the apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt). It's not surprising that you don't have one yet. That file lists Ubuntu packages to install via the `apt` command.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/codexaxor/Musical-Chord-Classification-Web-App/tree/codexaxor-patch) this is the repo. The app is built on Windows OS. And I added 'Aptfile' extra. Okay anyway. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: `libsndfile1-dev` works!

Comment: Worked for me, I had to add `libsndfile1-dev` as well

Comment: thank you chris, everything worked seamlessly

Answer (score 3):

Create an 'Aptfile' and add the following lines:

libasound2-dev
python-dev python-numpy python-setuptools libsndfile-dev

This worked for me.

Comment: This answer is brilliant, all I needed! I was running into the issue: "fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory" and installing this on my Mac wasn't the issue, I needed to figure out how to get Heroku to install the needed files.

To do that, I created the Aptfile you described and everything was good.