# Librosa Installation for Flask Heroku Deployment: "OSError: sndfile library not found" (H10 error)

Tags: python, macos, flask, heroku, librosa

I am deploying a Flask app of Heroku that uses librosa, but when I run the app, I get an H10 error. I went back into the logs and got this error, which is likely the cause of the H10 error:

```
2021-07-17T13:06:17.447032+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: sndfile library not found
```

requirements.txt:

```
git+https://github.com/CPJKU/madmom.git
ffmpeg==1.4
Flask==1.1.2
Jinja2==2.11.3
librosa==0.8.0
numpy==1.17.5
youtube-dl==2021.4.17
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

I've tried to install `libsndfile1`, tried to install librosa with conda, and tried to install librosa with homebrew (I am on MacOS) but none of those methods have worked.

Comment: can you paste the content your requirements.txt file by editing the question

Comment: @charchit requirements.txt is now in question

Comment: Have you checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57746160/15011621

Comment: @charchit I tried the first solution in the question you linked and that did not work, but the second one got rid of the `OSError: sndfile library not found` message, so thank you for that. However, my app is still crashing, but this time, it gives the following error: `ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject` I think this has something to do with the madmom package. Do you know a way to fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue but in my local machine, I followed this answer, it solved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066058/15011621

Answer (score 0):

When needing custom Linux dependencies on Heroku, I recommend switching to using Docker instead of Heroku buildpacks. Then you can get the same environment locally as you run on your servers. Here is the official Heroku documentation on [deploying with Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml).

For using librosa et.c you can base your Docker image on the offical [Python Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python). If you use one of the Debian variants, then you can install sndfile using `sudo apt-get install -yqq libsndfile1 libsndfile1-dev`. Note that this should be done before installing Python dependencies with pip.